# Extract values from JSON nested list and string array with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, geopandas

***I am trying to pull the coordinates from multiple neighborhoods in Boston, MA from a JSON dataset but am stuck trying to get just the first coordinate pair for each city; below is a small version of the Roslindale coordinates.***

```
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "Name": "Roslindale",
      "Acres": 1605.5682375,
      "SqMiles": 2.51,
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [
              -71.125927174853857,
              42.272013107957406
            ],
            [
              -71.125927174853857,
              42.272013107957406
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            [
              -71.125830766767592,
              42.272212845889705
            ],
            [
              -71.125830766767592,
              42.272212845889705
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            [
              -71.125767203228904,
              42.272315958536389
            ],
            [
              -71.125767203228904,
              42.272315958536389
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
```

*Right now I have pulled the data i want using*

```
for data in boston_neighborhoods:
    neighborhood_name = data['properties']['Name']
    neighborhood_id = data['properties']['Neighborhood_ID']
    neighborhood_size = data['properties']['SqMiles']
    neighborhood_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
    neighborhood_lat = neighborhood_latlon
    neighborhood_lon = neighborhood_latlon

    neighborhoods = neighborhoods.append({'Neighborhood': neighborhood_name,
                                          'Neighborhood_ID': neighborhood_id,
                                          'SqMiles': neighborhood_size,
                                          'Latitude': neighborhood_lat,
                                          'Longitude': neighborhood_lon}, ignore_index=True)
```

*This returns multiple coordinate pairs, but i only want the first pair, below is example output of what I am now returning:*

```
Latitude                   |           Longitude     
--------------------------------------------------------
[[[[-71.12592717485386,    |    [[[[-71.12592717485386, 
42.272013107957406], [...  |    42.272013107957406], [...
```

Comment: Basically you need lats in one column and all longs in another column?

Comment: yes that would help, but for each city there are about 1200 latitude and longitude pairs, and I only want to pull the first pair per city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be overkill, but [`JMESPath`](https://jmespath.org/) makes it really easy to query nested JSON structures like that one.

Traversing down the document, you first need to get every element in the array (`[*]`), then for each element you'll select items into an object (a Python dictionary). You'll select the neighborhood under `properties` and then `Name` (`properties.Name`). You do the same for similarly nested properties.

Coordinates live under `geometry.coordinates` which is an array of arrays of arrays of coordinate pairs.

```py
import jmespath
import pandas as pd

query = """
[*].{ 
    Neighborhood: properties.Name,
    Neighborhood_ID: properties.Neighborhood_ID, 
    SqMiles: properties.SqMiles, 
    Latitude: geometry.coordinates[0][0][0][0], 
    Longitude: geometry.coordinates[0][0][0][1] 
}
"""

compiled = jmespath.compile(query)
result = compiled.search(boston_neighborhoods)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result)
#   Neighborhood Neighborhood_ID  SqMiles   Latitude  Longitude
# 0   Roslindale            None     2.51 -71.125927  42.272013
```

Comment: Really nice answer, didn't know about JMESPath, thanks for sharing! +1 :)